# Object Promise message is displayed

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

```
    const readData = async () => {
      const data = window.contract.methods.getName().call();
      document.getElementById("dataArea").innerHTML = `Message is here: ${data}`;
```

why am i getting the message of **Object Promise** in `${data}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.call()` returns a Promise, you need to wait for it to resolve:

```js
      const data = await window.contract.methods.getName().call();
      document.getElementById("dataArea").innerHTML = `Message is here: ${data}`;
```